custom IAuthenticator in ckan
I am trying to implement the IAuthenticator in my ckan, here is the documentation link
https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.10/extensions/plugin-interfaces.html?highlight=authenti#ckan.plugins.interfaces.IAuthenticator
I wanted to connect to other databases to get my login user so I implemented the authentic() method and do whatever is necessary at my side to verify the credential entered by user, my problem is, I don't know how to redirect to another page after the credential is verified correctly. How can I redirect them to the main page?
